# Detect if there is more than one screen connected, from the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Is there a way in javascript, **from the browser**, to detect if there is any other screen connected, through HDMI or VGA or whatever?. For instance, in electron, there is the [screen API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/screen/) with methods like `getAllDisplays()` or events like `display-added` `display-removed`. Are there any npm package that expose some similar API for the browser?

Comment: No, that's impossible. You cannot access screen information from the browser. Why would you need to?

Comment: I wan to open some links in different screens, thinking in some slides viewer, and trying to avoid desktop app, but seems that's the way to go

Comment: I think you'll have to have the user open two browser windows for that and declare which is which.

Answer (score 0):

In theory the screen API can be accessed in the renderer process using Electron remote but the docs say the normal way of using remote doesn't work but doesn't provide a working

> Note: In the renderer / DevTools, window.screen is a reserved DOM property, so writing let {screen} = require('electron') will not work.

The above is from http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/screen/

A possible workaround would be to use the ipcRenderer API to send events to the Main process (that is capable of easily using the screen API as you have been doing so far) to do the screen operations you wanted to do.